# Применение внедрения зависимостей. Правильно ли?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

Взялся я за реализацию IoC для сервиса данных. Сделал вот так:

```
interface IDataService
{

}
```

и его реализация (возьмем для примера RpcJson):

```
class JsonRpcDataService : IDataService
{

}
```

Далее регистрируем их в IoC-контейнере. Тут все пока понятно.

Далее переходим к собственно к реализации. Я определил следующую структуру сервиса данных:

1. Модели - тут все понятно
2. Коллекторы - это вспомогательные классы для получения данных
3. Обработчики - вспомогательные классы для обработки данных (сохранения, например)

Опишем интерфейс модели:

```
interface IBook
{
   string Autor { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Коллектор:

```
interface IBooksCollector
{
   IEnumerable<IBook> GetItems();
   ...
}
```

И обработчик:

```
interface IBooksHandler
{
   void Save(IBook book);
   ...
}
```

Ну и, соответственно, для реализуем каждый из них для JsonRpc. Далее дополняем интерфейс `IDataService`:

```
interface IDataService
{
   IBook CreateBook();

   IBooksCollector CreateBooksCollector();

   IBooksHandler CreateBooksHandler();
}
```

И реализуем эти методы в `JsonRpcDataService`. Их я сделал для того, чтобы я на уровне `ViewModel` должен был бы связывать только IDataService с RpcJsonDataService, а не все интерфейсы с их реализациями. Чтобы в итоге я мог делать как-то так:

```
var dataService = IoC.Resolve<IDataService>();
// Создаем модель
IBook book = dataService.CreateBook();
```

Вместо

```
IBook book = IoC.Resolve<IBook>();
```

и где-то до этого связывание

```
IBook book = IoC.Register<IBook, Book>();
```

где `Book` - реализация `IBook` для `RpcJson`. Так как моделей может быть очень много, то вместо кучи строк вида:

```
IoC.Register<IModel, ModelClass>();
```

Все сводится к одной:

```
IoC.Register<IDataService, RpcJsonDataService>();
```

По ходу у меня появились вопросы, на которые я и прошу Вас ответить:

1. Правилен ли такой подход с созданием инстансов? Или может сделать фабрики вида `CreateModel<T>()`, в которую в качестве параметра `T` будет передаваться интерфейс, а фабрика уже будет решать что "отдать"?
2. Стоит ли вообще делать интерфейсы для моделей, или лучше описать их сразу? Выделил я их для того, чтобы не загромождать из атрибутами вида `[JsonProperty(...)]`, необходимые для сериализации, ведь эти атрибуты нужны только для сервера RpcJson

Comment: Если моделей очень много, то класс IDataService распухнет, и вместо кучи строк с регистрацией типов в контейнере, будет один очень большой класс. Мне кажется ответ на первый вопрос: нет не правильно, при использовании контейнера он будет выполнять роль фабрики которая "будет решать, что отдать".

Comment: Ещё, очень рекомендую книжку "Симан М. - Внедрение зависимостей в .NET". Там очень доходчиво и с примерами объясняется подход внедрения зависимостей.

Comment: @cybrex, если их станет много, то можно сделать отдельные фабрики для моделей, коллекторов и обработчиков. Просто при таком подходе я регистрирую одну зависимость, а если сделать регистрацию всех зависимостей, то это накладно

Comment: Не совсем понимаю почему накладно? Потому что много однотипного кода регистрации? Наверняка регистрацию можно вынести в XML файл, большинство контейнеров это поддерживают.

Comment: Ещё, есть [авто регистрация типов](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701882/auto-register-all-interfaces-with-unity). Возможно ссылка не очень удачная, но пример для конкретного контейнера можно нагуглить.

Comment: @cybrex, да, много однотипных.  А это подразумевает возможность ошибки. В идеале хотелось бы просто "сказать" - используй этот сервис.  За авторегистрацию и XML спасибо, погуглю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В первую очередь - неверно ваше желание обойтись минимальным количеством регистраций компонентов. Если у вас 40 компонентов нет ничего зазорного в том чтобы регистрировать все 40 компонентов в контейнере. Это не будет ошибкой. Более того, хотя многие контейнеры и поддерживают в том или ином виде автоматическую регистрацию компонентов, Castle Windsor например, насколько мне известно, *обязывает* вас явно регистрировать каждый компонент, и такой подход с явной регистрацией имеет определенный смысл. Но здесь вы вправе выбрать то что вам ближе - автоматическая регистрация или явная регистрация каждого компонента, оба подхода имеют свои преимущества и недостатки.

Второе - вы ошибочно ассоциируете регистрацию компонента и последующее получение его из контейнера. Если вы написали `IoC.Register<IComponent, Component>();` это не означает что потом для получения `IComponent` вы обязаны получать его из контейнера. Как правило, вы регистрируете n - компонентов, но из IoC контейнера - запрашиваете только один. Например, если у вас ASP-MVC приложение, в нем может быть много компонентов (контроллеры, сервисы и т.д.), но запрос компонента из IoC контейнера у вас будет всего один - это будет запрос контроллера в фабрике контроллеров. Чтобы понять зачем регистрировать 10 компонентов, если запрашиваться будет только 1 читайте про основные паттерны внедрения зависимостей - *внедрение конструктора* и *внедрение свойства*.

Ответы на ваши вопросы:

1. Использование фабрик для создания моделей - нормальный подход. Создавать фабричный метод вида `CreateModel<T>()` где T интерфейс модели, не имеет смысла. Подумайте, чем этот метод будет принципиально отличаться от аналогичного метода IoC-контейнера?
2. Скорее всего не стоит делать интерфейсы для моделей. Использование IoC контейнера вовсе не обязывает вас делать интерфейсы для каждого класса в вашем приложении. Для моделей интерфейсы чаще всего не нужны.

По формулировке вашего вопроса видно что вы довольно плохо ориентируетесь в теме и двигаетесь в неверном направлении. Вам стоит потратить немного времени на ее изучение, прежде чем проектировать приложение.  В частности паттерны внедрения зависимостей, упомянутые выше (*внедрение конструктора* и *внедрение свойства*), существенно важнее для понимания DI, чем любые вопросы, связанные с регистрацией компонентов в IoC-контейнере. Вообще внедрение зависимостей это как раз про эти паттерны, а IoC-контейнер это просто инструмент, облегчающий построение приложения с использованием DI, и DI можно применять вообще без IoC-контейнера.

В комменатриях  @cybrex посоветовал прочитать книгу **Симан М. - Внедрение зависимостей в .NET**. Я присоденияюсь к этому совету, почитайте - не пожалеете.

Comment: @Donil Скорректировал ответ - изменил ответ на первый вопрос

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ! Да, действительно, ориентируюсь пока плохо. Интерфейсы я выделил для того, чтобы они были. так сказать, "чистыми", чтобы не загромождать их, как я уже писал, атрибутами вида JsonProperty. Просто сейчас у меня один провайдер - JsonRpc и один атрибут на поле, для сериализации/десериализации json. А если появится еще один? Скажем XmlRpc, то появятся еще и атрибуты для сериализации/десериаизации XML. А так у каждого провайдера своя реализация моделей со своим, необходимым только ему набором атрибутов

Comment: @Donil значит интерфейсы нужны, но опять же вам совсем не обязательно регистрировать их в IoC-контейнере. Например, ваши модели могут реализовывать интерфейсы из фреймворка `IDisposable` или `ICloneable`, но вы из-за этого не станете регистрировать эти интерфейсы в контейнере. Точно так же в вашем коде могут быть ваши собственные интерфейсы, которые не являются интерфейсами _компонентов_ и не регистрируются в IoC-контейнере.

Comment: Это я понимаю (про `IDisposable` и `ICloneable`). Но если у меня есть ViewModel, с конструктором вида `BookVM(IBook)`, то интерфейс модели `IBook` нужно регистрировать, так? Мне же может понадобиться создать новую книгу.

Comment: И что вы будете делать когда вам потребуется создать новую книгу? Вызовете `IoC.Resolve<IBook>();`?

Comment: Не все ваши классы должны браться из IoC-контейнера. Из IoC-контейнера берутся только _сервисы_ (_компоненты_), модели как правило либо извлекаются из хранилища данных либо создаются самостоятельно (с помощью фабрик, а вот эти фабрики уже регистрируются в IoC-контейнере).

Comment: Вообще, я планировал сделать `IoC.GetInstance<BookVM>();` >либо создаются самостоятельно (с помощью фабрик, а вот эти фабрики уже регистрируются в IoC-контейнере) Вот. Значит мой подход с фабриками в вопросе отчасти верен?

Comment: _Значит мой подход с фабриками в вопросе отчасти верен?_ - да