# Создание mvc проекта с onion архитектурой и использованием ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Изучаю mvc 5 на metanit. Добрался до пункта архитектура приложений. И тут возникло много вопросов. Изучаю конкретно onion архитектуру и принцип UnitOfWork. И в связи с этими пунктами у меня появился вопрос:

Если я буду использовать принцип UnitOfWork мне не придётся создавать конструктор контроллера с параметрами. И получается всё уже работает без Ninject и суть вопроса в следующем. Зачем тогда вообще нужно внедрение зависимостей с помощью Ninject.

Comment: IoС Ninject нужен для слабо связности кода.

Comment: @Yaroslav поподробнее можно?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446783/261244